# How to handle an OP's edit that changes the question

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I have answered [this question about jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700005/jquery-increment-id-number-when-dynamically-appending-elements) and provided some code based on the code posted in the original question.

However, after I and others posted answers, the OP changed significantly the code in the question, changing the markup and style names. The question remains more or less the same in terms of what the OP wants to achieve, but the code changed a lot. I feel future readers won't see the link between the question's code and the code of the answers (all of them).

The OP has accepted my answer *after* they edited the question.

How would you handle such a case? I am tempted to edit the question to revert to original one, possibly improving the wording at the same time. Is it OK to do so?

Comment: Perhaps edit the original code back into the OP with a **Originial Code:** header.  In the general sense these are a case-by-case thing, I think.