# How to handle questions whose meaning is changed radically after an useful answer has been given?

Tags: discussion

I just stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632129/getting-a-class-name-from-iside-a-another-classes-method). The questioner posted the expected output of his code. Shortly afterwards he received an answer that would fully solve his problem.

The questioner then edited his question and changed the expected output (not on purpose, only a small mistake) which made the answer completely invalid in the new context.

Fortunately the person that gave the answer reacted souvereign and made a temporary edit stating that he would need to edit the answer to comply with the new context.

That leads me to my question. If someone just would have posted the answer and did not react to the changes (because he did not notice that there was an edit or other reasons) how should we treat the answer?

In the old context the answer would not be wrong so downvoting would be unfair. So would the best option be to draw the answering persons attention to the new circumstances by commenting? And then to flag it if there are no further reactions?

Comment: How about pointing out the existing answer and the change of meaning to the person posting the question? If there is a big change in the question, especially after a good answer to the original question, I think the best path is to wrap up the old question by accepting the answer, and create a new question with the new required output.

Comment: _"How to behave"_? Completely lose it. Just flip out. ;-)

Comment: The edit to the question seems to have happened in the 5 minute grace period as there is no revision history. Normally the advice for edits that drasticall change the meaning of existing questions is to roll back the edit and tell OP to ask a new question, but that's mostly meant for cases where OP posts a follow-up as an edit to an already answered question. The grace period and the fact that the answer was posted _after_ the edit means this is not applicable here.

Comment: @Cerbrus made my day :D I'm not a native speaker though

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255244/how-to-handle-an-ops-edit-that-changes-the-question?rq=1

Comment: See also: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)