# How do I make the asker understand that edits that change the whole question are not allowed? Can someone please roll it back for me?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, specific-question, specific-edit

I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72950021/16136190) [a question about Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949572/how-can-a-function-to-a-button), and the OP accepted the answer. I don't think the OP understands SO's system. I know I can roll it back to one of the good revisions, but I don't have enough reputation to.

Can someone please roll it back for me?

And what is the best way to make the OP understand why edits that change the question completely are not allowed? (because the thread as a whole will look senseless, won't help future readers etc.) Should I leave a comment or just let it be after the rollback?

I've seen:

1. [How to handle an OP's edit that changes the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255244/how-to-handle-an-ops-edit-that-changes-the-question)
2. [Dealing with questions that are edited after my answer has been accepted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted)
3. [Should a question edit be rolled back if it appears to be a follow-up to an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299405/should-a-question-edit-be-rolled-back-if-it-appears-to-be-a-follow-up-to-an-answ)

Comment: You've seen those three questions, but your question isn't answered? What is still unclear?

Comment: @Tom, whether I should leave a comment or not if it gets rolled back. And can you please do that for me?

Comment: Which revision, specifically, are you looking have it rolled back to? There are some huge edits to that question; it looks like the context has been changed significantly multiple times with edits like *"1793 characters in body"*, *"added 9023 characters in body"*, *"deleted 16788 characters in body"*, etc.

Comment: I have rolled it back to revision 3 as revision 4 removes code that the answer is referring to.

Comment: Since you "don't have enough reputation" to rollback, flag it for moderator attention, as per the discussion here (which seems more relevant to your case since you are at <2k): [Should I raise a moderator flag or edit directly if I don't have enough reputation to rollback a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280720/2745495)

Comment: *"And what is the best way to make the OP understand why edits that change the question completely are not allowed?"* - rollback. Lead by example. Hopefully if it happens a few times to them, they catch on.

Comment: This looks to not be the first time the OP has [done this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72778561/revisions) (link may not work for <10k rep).

Comment: The question you answered, which you reverted to an earlier revision, has already been deleted by the community.  This begs the question of why a question, that was deemed to be such a low quality question it was removed, even answered in the to begin with?

Comment: A canonical is *[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)*.